# Can you refer to a friend operator defined inside a struct?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, function-pointers, friend-function

Using the friend operator idiom:

```
struct Foo {
  friend Foo operator+(Foo, Foo) { return {}; }
};

// which is synonymous to the slightly less pretty:
struct Bar {
  friend Bar operator+(Bar, Bar); // optional
};
inline Bar operator+(Bar, Bar) { return {}; }
```

I basically want the function pointer of the `operator+` for `Foo`.

With `Bar` I can say the following:

```
auto fn = static_cast<Bar (*)(Bar, Bar)>(&operator+);
fn({},{});
```

However, if I do the same to the `Foo` version, g++ and clang++ inform me:

```
// g++ 4.8.3
error: ‘operator+’ not defined
   auto f = static_cast<Foo (*)(Foo, Foo)>(&operator+);
                                                    ^

// clang++ 3.2-11
error: use of undeclared 'operator+'
  auto f = static_cast<Foo (*)(Foo, Foo)>(&operator+);
                                           ^
```

Is this intrinsically impossible or is there a way to refer to the function?

Comment: Inlined friend functions are only visible through ADL. By the way, if you didn't know, you can replace `Type{}` with `{}` in quite a few cases.

Comment: @chris: Yes, you're right about the `{}` thing. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

If a friend function is only declared within a class definition, then it can't be found by qualified or unqualified lookup, only by argument-dependent lookup. This means that you can call the function, but can't take its address.

If you want to take the address, then you'll need to declare it in the surrounding namespace as well.

Alternatively, you could use a lambda rather than an old-school function pointer:

```
auto f = [](Foo f1, Foo f2){return f1+f2;}
```

Comment: Thought of a lambda as well, it just struck me as odd, that I couldn't refer to the function. Thanks for the explanation.